# How to check whether date time in null or not using c#

Tags: c#

I have a proxy stub where my variable is of datetime type in the proxy stub and i am assinging that date to my view by getting it from model in need to check whether date time is null or not if null i should show not available in UI

Proxy stub

```
[DataMember(Order = 9)]

        public System.DateTime? FromDate
        {
            get
            {
                return _FromDate;
            }
            set
            {
                this.SetDirty();
                this._FromDate = value;
            }
        }
```

Model

```
model.FromDate = Convert.ToDateTime(MemberInfo.FromDate);
```

View

```
 @if ((Model.FromDate!= null))
                {
                    <p>  @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FromDate) </p>
                }
                else
                {
                    <p> N/A</p>
                }
```

What i tried is

```
if(model.FromDate!=null)
{
model.FromDate = Convert.ToDateTime(MemberInfo.FromDate);
}
else{
model.FromDate="Not Available";
}
```

But i am getting string to date time conversion error

Comment: `FromDate.HasValue` Its nullable so

Comment: if(model.FromDate!=null)
{
model.FromDate = Convert.ToDateTime(MemberInfo.FromDate);
}
else{
model.FromDate="Not Available";
}  i had tried this But i am getting string to date time conversion error

Comment: model.FromDate is a DateTime, you cannot assign a string to it (Not Available)

Comment: Conversions have nothing to do with nullability. The error means that `MemberInfo.FromDate` contains a string that can't be parsed. Why is that a string to begin wtih? What does it contain?

Comment: then how can i resolve this issue

Comment: `model.FromDate="Not Available";`Not Available is string u cant assign it to FromDate c# is strongly typed

Comment: @testgiver you haven't posted anything about conversions yet. What does that string contain? Where did it come from?

Comment: Actually i will get date from back end if that date is N/A in back end i need to show Not Available in front end

Comment: @AvinashReddy that would result in a compilation error, not a conversion error at runtime. I suspect this isn't the actual code

Comment: @testgiver what back end? Please post the relevant information, code in the question. Right now there's nothing that can help, apart from the certainty that `MemberInfo.FromDate` doesn't contain a valid date for your locale

Comment: @testgiver if `FromDate` is really a `DateTime?` you'll get a compilation error. This can't be the actual code.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Actually i will get date from back end if that date is N/A in back end i need to show Not Available in front end

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos but he is still trying to use it so I mentioned

Comment: @testgiver wt is the exception u are  getting in this line `model.FromDate = Convert.ToDateTime(MemberInfo.FromDate);`

Comment: model.FromDate = Convert.ToDateTime(MemberInfo.FromDate); Here i am not getting any exception if i am using if else condition if(model.FromDate!=null)
{
model.FromDate = Convert.ToDateTime(MemberInfo.FromDate);
}
else{
model.FromDate="Not Available";
} i am getting cannot implicitly convert string to system.datetime

Comment: try this [Checking to see if a DateTime variable has had a value assigned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305154/checking-to-see-if-a-datetime-variable-has-had-a-value-assigned)

Comment: @valerianHavaux i had already tried this its not working

Comment: @testgiver for me the problem is more global . Do you have tried this kind of result pattern ? [The Operation Result Pattern](https://medium.com/@cummingsi1993/the-operation-result-pattern-a-simple-guide-fe10ff959080) maybee helpfull in this kinds of situations

Answer (score 1):

`if(model.FromDate!=null)`

model.FromDate is actually nullable so null checking will be `model.FromDate.HasValue`

if `model.FromDate = Convert.ToDateTime(MemberInfo.FromDate);` giving exception in non formated date strings the use tryparse

```
  DateTime resultDate;
  if (DateTime.TryParse(MemberInfo.FromDate, out resultDate))
```

`model.FromDate="Not Available";`

this cannot be done in c# as it is strongly typed so use another variable

**Model**

```
DateTime resultDate;
if (DateTime.TryParse(MemberInfo.FromDate, out resultDate))
   model.FromDate.Value = resultDate;
else
   model.FromDate.Value=null;
```

**View**

```
 @if ((Model.FromDate.HasValue))
     {
          <p>  @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FromDate) </p>
     }
  else
      {
         <p> Not Available</p>
      }
```

**As Per Comment**

`model.FromDate=MemberInfo.FromDate`

Comment: but still i am facing the same issue cannot convert date time to string you try to declare a from date variable with date time in model and retrieve it from db if we have date in db e need to show that date in ui else we need to show not available

Comment: @testgiver like this ??

Comment: cannot convert from 'System.DateTime?' to 'string' now this is the error

Comment: @testgiver which line?  `MemberInfo.FromDate` this one? then `MemberInfo.FromDate.ToString()`

Comment: (DateTime.TryParse(MemberInfo.FromDate, out resultDate)) this line

Comment: if u are getting in datetime why are even converting?

Comment: i am not converting i am using if else condition to show  not available